# Don’t go there, they’ve laid mines there

Tags: usage

Suppose in a war soldiers of one side are going through a road. Suddenly one of the soldiers notices that some of the other soldiers are getting into a minefield. That soldier wants to say something to stop them enter the area. Does the following sentence sound natural to you:

> - Don’t go there, they’ve laid mines there.

Comment: I think it'd be urgent to warn the other soldiers, so that soldier should say, "Stop! There are mines [over there]!"

Comment: Natural, but not particularly urgent.   In real-life circumstances, the warning would not be a full sentence, at least not in the situation you have presented, where someone is about to step into a minefield.  It would be very brief:  *Stop! Minefield!*

Comment: Another possibility is "That field is *mined*."

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a correct sentence. It is a run-on sentence, because you have spliced two sentences together with only a comma.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence

People do use run-on sentences frequently, but they are still not grammatically correct.

You could add a coordinating conjunction, like

> Don’t go there, for they’ve laid mines there.

This is grammatically correct, but it sounds very literary and formal, and it doesn't really seem to me like something you would utter in the middle of a battlefield.

I would just write it as two sentences:

> Don't go there! They've laid mines there.

Comment: Using a semicolon instead of a comma would also fix the error, without the need for an additional word or sentence.

Comment: While it's not strictly grammatically correct, it's a perfectly reasonable piece of colloquial spoken English, which is not generally concerned with niceties of punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a perfectly acceptable sentence. The term [*minelayer*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/minelayer) is also acceptable for someone or something who lays mines.